# C/C++ Allegro program causes Windows 7 to switch to Aero Basic

Tags: c, windows, winapi, allegro

I'm just trying out the allegro library, and here is the code which I've got so far:

```
#include <allegro.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    allegro_init();  // initialize the allegro libraries
    install_keyboard(); // initialize keyboard functions
    
    set_color_depth(16); // set the color depth
    set_gfx_mode(GFX_AUTODETECT_WINDOWED, 640, 480, 0, 0); // set up 640*480px window
    
    BITMAP *pic = NULL;
    pic = load_bitmap("C:/picture.bmp", NULL); // load the picture
    blit(pic, screen, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1000, 1000);

    readkey();
    destroy_bitmap(pic);
    return 0;
} 
END_OF_MAIN()
```

It works fine, but when I run it, while the program's window is open, Windows 7 changes the theme from Aero to Aero basic. If you aren't sure what I mean, this pops up (I got this from Google, which is why it says Vista rather than Windows 7):

[image: http://www.suitedcowboys.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/01/010607_0906_HelloVistai28.png]
<sub>(source: [suitedcowboys.com](http://www.suitedcowboys.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/01/010607_0906_HelloVistai28.png#))</sub>

1. Why?
2. How can I ensure that this doesn't happen?

Comment: When you write "production" code, be sure to check return values, especially things that have good reason to fail, like `load_bitmap`.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I'd never release rubbish code like this. xD

Thanks though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Aero needs color set to 32 bit](http://microsoft.blognewschannel.com/archives/2007/03/25/why-your-aero-glass-might-disappear-all-of-a-sudden/), but you're setting it to 16:

`set_color_depth(16);`

Comment: I love simple solutions. :) Thanks for the speedy answer. Will this impact the programs cross-platform capabilities though? According to the tutorial I'm following it does, but it does look pretty old.

Comment: What platforms use 16-bit color depth today? Most have 24 or 32.

Comment: jpyllman: Have you ever used RDP (Terminal Services) over a remote connection? I regularly use it at 8-bit color. It's also common for people to run VMs at lower bit depths because the hardware is easier to emulate.

Comment: konforce's answer shows how to use the current color depth. Not much I can add.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have good reason to use a specific color depth, do this:

```
int cd = desktop_color_depth();
if (cd < 15) cd = 32;
set_color_depth(cd);
```

While generally not a problem today, many older video cards only support one of 15/16 bit and one of 24/32 bit.

If you need to use 8-bit color depth because you use a palette, then just use the `GFX_GDI` driver for maximum compatibility.